# IE8: browser-cache and ajax

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, web-applications

I developed a webapplication with ajax.

its fine with firefox but under IE8 some of my ajax dynamics (e.g. changing a div after a button etc.) are not working. only if I disable the browser-cache (F12 - Cache - always reload from server).

think IE doesnt check that a ajax-response has changed a part of the site or something else. 
any ideas i can handle this with this option on??

I tried random-numbers in the request or timestamps in the response but didnt work.

thanks!
ch

Answer (score 0):

try with.
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what server side language you use... I used code below at the server side(in the ...aspx.cs file):

```
        Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "No-Cache");
        Response.Write...
```